# Failed to get the 'some' field from optional

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

astoundingly, typing this error into the Stack Overflow search returns no results that actually mention this error 0.0

So I have an `Event` object in my Swift IOS App which is saved as a document on Firestore that looks like this

[image]

The `start` and `end` fields are Timestamps.

Over on xcode when the `Event` collection is queried, the results are decoded into `Event`s with this initialiser

```
init(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
       self.id = document.documentID
       let d = document.data()
       self.title = d!["title"] as? String
       
       let stamp = d!["start"] as? Timestamp
       let estamp = d!["end"] as? Timestamp
       
       self.start = stamp?.dateValue()
       self.end = estamp?.dateValue()
       /* 
          There is a breakpoint here!
       */
       self.creator = d!["user"] as? String
       
       self.isAllDay = (d!["isAllDay"] as? Bool)!
       
       self.isPrivate = d!["isPrivate"] as! Bool
       
       self.count = (d!["count"] as? String)!
       
       self.date = d?["day"] as? String
       self.month = d?["month"] as? String
       self.year = d?["year"] as? String
       
       self.bridgesDays = doesEventBridgeDays()
       //MARK: re-implement these functions
       
       isInvitee()
       
   }
```

I've just swapped this over from using Strings to Timestamps and i now have `unexpectedly found nil` errors for the `start` and `end` fields on the app.

a breakpoint shows me this:

[image]

As you can see, the start and end fields now say `Failed to get the 'some' field from optional start/end` (`start` and `end` are now both `Date` objects)

I either don't understand what i'm reading online, or there are no questions/blog posts etc about this on the internet so

what does this mean?

and how do I fix it?

happy to answer any further questions to help resolve this issue :)

Thanks :)

**Extra information***

[image]

Comment: Use tags so that readers won't be misled with the actual intensions of your topic.

Comment: @ElTomato what tags would you recommend here?.. I thought Swift was enough, given that it's a swift Error (as far as i know)

Comment: Use Firestore, iOS.  Not everybody uses Firebase or Firestore.  Not everybody develops iOS apps whether he or she writes code in Swift.

Comment: @ElTomato didn't think of that, updated the tags, thanks :)

Comment: @Andy Yeah those tags are important. If you pick good tags, people that specialize in those areas are much more likely to find your question, and then you'll get quicker & better answers. In the sea of over 300k `swift` questions and lots new questions popping up all the time, your question may otherwise get missed. Useful tip ;)

Comment: What do you see when you `print(d)` or stop the debugger on `d` -- what is contained in the `start` and `end` fields?

Comment: @jnpdx I added a screenshot of `d[end]`  from the debugger, to the bottom of the question (`d[start]` is the same, with a different `seconds` value)

Both `d[end and start]` are `Timestamps`

Comment: right... i'm really confused.... I haven't changed anything, but now the nil value error has stopped... the debugger still says `failed to get the some field from optional` for the start and end properties, but everything is working perfectly now 0.o....so i guess... thanks? 0.o I'd still like to know what that message means, if anybody knows?.... it could be useful to someone in the future :)

Comment: Your  cast of the retrieved value to a timestamp is failable, so if the cast fails the value would be nil.  As you then convert these into dates using optional chaining, this means that start and end would also be nil in this circumstance (and their types are actually `Date?` rather than 'Date')

Comment: Show the `Event` object in its entirety.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue @Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is failing because your Event object in code is trying to store your 'start' and 'end' properties as a Date? but you're retrieving them from Firebase Firestore as a Timestamp.

You'll need to do an intermediate step to unwrap the values and then get the date object.

```
if let end = data["end"] as? Timestamp {
    self.end = end.dateValue()
}
```

Also, you should really be unwrapping the document.data() safely to avoid using the d! and risking a crash.

```
if let data = document.data(){
    // extract values
}
```

Finally, it may be worth reading the document on sending / retrieving custom objects with Firestore. It makes everything a lot easier.

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("Event").document(id).getDocument { (document, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
    }
    guard let document = document else {
        // failed to unwrap document
        return
    }
    if document.exists {
        let result = Result {
            try document.data(as: Event.self)
        }
        switch result {
        case .success(let event):
            if let event = event {
                // do something with Event object
            } else {
                // failed to unwrap Event
            }
        case .failure:
            // failed to form Event
        }
    } else {
        // document doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, I hadn’t solved this issue yet, the crash stopped on it’s own ‍♂️ So I put it in my “later” pile ….. I’ll give this a try next chance I get with the computer (I share it with 5 other people )….. thanks :)